# cmake error "CMake Error: The source directory ".../p4c/build/[-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE" does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm getting the cmake error when installing [p4c](https://github.com/p4lang/p4c). Below is the cmake command to be run

```
cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE|DEBUG] [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>] [-DENABLE_DOCS=ON (default off)] [-DENABLE_P4RUNTIME_TO_PD=OFF (default on)]
```

I'm getting the below error

> CMake Error: The source directory "/home/users/phani/p4c/build/[-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE" does not exist.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
>   DEBUG]: command not found

source files, CmakeLists.txt are in path "/home/users/phani/p4c", build is done is seperate subdirectory as shown in the link. Please help me to resolve the error

Comment: small correction, cmake command that I was executing is "cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE|DEBUG] [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local] [-DENABLE_DOCS=ON ] [-DENABLE_P4RUNTIME_TO_PD=OFF]"

Answer (score 6):

The syntax:

```
cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE|DEBUG] [-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>] [-DENABLE_DOCS=ON (default off)] [-DENABLE_P4RUNTIME_TO_PD=OFF (default on)]
```

is commonly used to quickly describe what options can be added or not to a command line.

To perform a simple build, do

```
cmake ..
```

If you want to specify the build type, you do:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
```

or

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
```

etc.

In other words, when you see

```
command [option] [option=val1|val2]
```

arguments under `[]` are optional, and char `|` means "or". You should not write these characters in the real command line you type in your terminal